# How to move an element in a struct matrix only once?

Tags: c, matrix

I have a matrix created from a struct like this:

```
typedef struct Animal{
  void* fuerza;
  char tipo_fuerza;
  void* velocidad;
  char tipo_velocidad;
  void* resistencia;
  char tipo_resistencia;
  void (*reproduccion)(struct Animal*, struct Animal*, struct Animal*);
  void (*comerHuir)(struct Animal*, struct Animal*);
} Animal;
```

and I asked for memory with calloc like this

```
Animal** matriz = (Animal**)calloc(1000,sizeof(Animal*));
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    matriz[i] = (Animal*)calloc(1000,sizeof(Animal));
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        matriz[i][j].velocidad = calloc(1,sizeof(Animal));
        matriz[i][j].fuerza = calloc(1,sizeof(Animal));
        matriz[i][j].resistencia = calloc(1,sizeof(Animal));
    }
}
```

To create an animal, I request data from the console, and it is assigned like this. 'e' stands for int, 'c' stands for char and 'f' stands for float.

```
scanf(" %c",&a->tipo_fuerza);
switch (a->tipo_fuerza) {
    case 'e':
        scanf(" %d",&entero);
        *((int*)a->fuerza) = entero;
        break;
    case 'c':
        scanf(" %c",&caracter);
        *((char*)a->fuerza) = caracter;
        break;
    case 'f':
        scanf(" %f",&flotante);
        *((float*)a->fuerza) = flotante;
        break;
}
```

I do a lot more. That was just an example

I also assigned the corresponding attributes void (*reproduccion) and void (*comerHuir) from other functions I create, just linking with a function.

In this homework, I have to create a time iteration. That means, that when I select that option, every valid and created Animal has to move only once and in a random direction (25% to move up, down, left, and right).

The problem is I have no idea how to do that.

Example:

[image: This is the iteration 0 (original position of the Animals) and the arrow represents where they are going to move]

This is iteration 0 (original position of the Animals) and the arrow represents where they are going to move

[image]

This is the result, two animals will collide and make some actions I can handle on my own. And the other animal just moved once in the down direction.

Also, how the example showed, the matrix is cyclic. I'm not sure if that is the word in English, but that means that when an Animal faces a matrix limit, it continues in the other limit.

I tried to implement a solution with two nested for, but in this case, the Animal moves to the right. It continues moving it to another position. I don't want that!

My solution was this one. **The problem is: for example: if I create an Animal in matriz[0][0], and that Animal moves to the left, the iterator will move it again! I don't want that!**

I don't think is necessary to explain those functions in the code. They do stuff out of the range of my question.

```
void Iteracion(Animal** Mundo){
//0 == izq, 1 == arriba, 2 == derecha, 3 == abajo;

int izq;
int arriba;
int der;
int abajo;
int movimiento = 0;

for (int column = 0; column < 1000; column++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < 1000; row ++) {
    
    if (Mundo[column][row].tipo_fuerza != '\0') {
        movimiento = rand() % 4;

        switch (movimiento) {
           case 0:
                izq = Ciclica(row, 0);  
                if (ComprobarAnimal(&Mundo[column][izq])==1) {
                    if (ComprobarAnimal(&Mundo[column][Ciclica(izq, 0)])==0) {
                        Reproducir(&Mundo[column][row], &Mundo[column][izq], &Mundo[column][Ciclica(izq, 0)]);
                    }
                    else if (ComprobarAnimal(&Mundo[Ciclica(column, 1)][izq])==0) {
                        Reproducir(&Mundo[column][row], &Mundo[column][izq], &Mundo[Ciclica(column, 1)][izq]);
                    }
                    else if (ComprobarAnimal(&Mundo[column][Ciclica(izq, 2)])==0) {
                        Reproducir(&Mundo[column][row], &Mundo[column][izq], &Mundo[column][Ciclica(izq, 2)]);
                    }
                    else if (ComprobarAnimal(&Mundo[Ciclica(column, 3)][izq])==0) {
                        Reproducir(&Mundo[column][row], &Mundo[column][izq], &Mundo[Ciclica(column, 3)][izq]);
                    }


                    ComerOHuir(&Mundo[column][row], &Mundo[column][izq]);

                    if (EleccionHuirSiempre == 1) {
                        CrearOMover(Mundo, &Mundo[column][row]);
                        EleccionHuirSiempre = 0;
                    }

                }
                else {
                    MoverAnimal(&Mundo[column][row], &Mundo[column][izq]);
                    Mundo[column][izq].reproduccion = Mundo[column][row].reproduccion;
                    Mundo[column][izq].comerHuir = Mundo[column][row].comerHuir;
                    Borrar(&Mundo[column][row]);
                }

                break;
                ...
```

I hope I am being clear enough. Any help is welcome!

Comment: I forgot to say that to create an Animal, I do a lot more. That was just an example

Comment: Please [edit] if you have to change something. Also, please provide a [mre] which demonstrates what you describe.

Comment: You dont need an {X,Y} matrix of animals. You only need N animals, each having {x,y,state,direction,speed,...}

Comment: I added a part of my code to my attempt of solution. Is that enough or should I add more things?

Comment: If you are entering 1000 animals by hand by typing at a keyboard, your debugging process is going to be painful.  If you do so, you are almost certainly not doing so from a "console".  All consoles are tty's, but most ttys are not consoles.  If you are *not* entering the data by hand (I truly hope you're not) but just reading it from a prepared data source, you still *must* check the value returned by `scanf`.  Always.  Every single time.

Comment: @wildplasser OP wants collision detection, probably an array with all the states is the easiest; perhaps an animal could be a link in a each position a linked list. It takes some planning.

Comment: Are you used to Python? Perhaps `unsigned` is easier than having polymorphic types. Reminds me of [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life).